# Convert month number to month name from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I convert month number to month name if have following records:

eg.

```
select date from tableClient;

17.01.07
18.02.08
18.03.08
18.04.08
18.05.08
18.06.08
18.07.08
18.08.08
```

Expected result is :

```
17.January.07
18.February.08
18.March.08
18.April.08
......
```

How to convert just MM from that that record?

PS. I have to write one query where exists two or three conditions, eg.

```
    select id, firstName, lastName, date from tableClient, tableActivity 
where tableClient.id = tableActivity.id and tableActivity.status= 'YES' 
AND tableActiviy.type = 'SMS';
```

Condition: date must be in the form :eg. 01.January.03

Comment: what is the datatype of `date` column is `date` or string datatypes like `varchar2/nvarchar` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `to_char()` function with `trim()` function to get rid off extra spaces after month name:

```
select trim(to_char(sysdate, 'dd.Month')) || '.' || to_char(sysdate,'yy') from dual;
```

With your example:

```
select id, firstName, lastName, trim(to_char(date, 'dd.Month')) || '.' || to_char(date,'yy') 
from tableClient, tableActivity 
where tableClient.id = tableActivity.id and tableActivity.status= 'YES' 
AND tableActiviy.type = 'SMS';
```

Comment: No need to use `TRIM`, use `FM`.

Comment: You are right, it is even shorter:
`select (to_char(sysdate, 'dd.fmMonth.yy')) from dual;`

Answer (score 0):

Use **TO_CHAR** with `FMMONTH` to **display** the date in your **desired format**.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216),

> Format Model Modifiers
>
> The FM and FX modifiers, used in format models in the TO_CHAR
>   function, control blank padding and exact format checking.
>
> A modifier can appear in a format model more than once. In such a
>   case, each subsequent occurrence toggles the effects of the modifier.
>   Its effects are enabled for the portion of the model following its
>   first occurrence, and then disabled for the portion following its
>   second, and then reenabled for the portion following its third, and so
>   on.
>
> FM Fill mode. Oracle uses trailing blank characters and leading zeroes
>   to fill format elements to a constant width. The width is equal to the
>   display width of the largest element for the relevant format model:

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-FMMONTH-YY') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE
---------------
09-MARCH-16

SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('17.01.07','dd.mm.yy'), 'DD-fmMONTH-fmYY') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE
---------------
17-JANUARY-07
```

Comment: @GoranBartBartolić See another example. Use `fmYY`. No need to use `trim` explicitly, it is unnecessary, just use `fm`.

Comment: @GoranBartBartolić Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for `SQL Server`,

```
SELECT FORMAT(date,'dd.MMMM.yy') AS date
FROM tableClient;
```

Example,

[image]

Comment: "Format" : invalid identifier.. I work in SQL developer

Comment: Neither `FORMAT` nor `now()` exist in Oracle.

Comment: Is SQL server anywhere mention in the question?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : No. But mentioned "SQL" in tag. Also it is not mentioned in this question that this is for Oracle db.